# Get text from server in a way as simple as getting an <img>

Tags: html, ajax, image, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

Requesting *bytes* from a server (possibly another domain) is very simple if it's an image:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/test.jpg" />
```

It won't produce any CrossOrigin isssue.

However requiring *text* from another server needs AJAX or `XMLHttpRequest` (I know about how to do it), and can possibly lead to a CrossOrigin issue.

Is there really no

```
<div innerText-src="http://www.example.com/getsometext.php?id=178"></div>
```

?

**If so, why?** Why has there been, historically, a particular treatment for images?

Comment: use `iframe`...

Comment: @PranavCBalan yes but an `iframe` is heavier than just embedding some text, it also creates (I just re-checked) a new "document" inside the document, with a new `<html><body>` etc. It's heavier than just embedding a few text bytes.

Comment: You can create an Ajax function that checks for elements with the `innerText-src` attribute. That way it would take the given URL & output the content in the element. It's pretty easy but the given URL must provide the text only otherwise you'd have to manually find the element the content is in – also would be slow af if there are multiple elements like this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the given URL only outputs the content you're looking for, it can easily be done with Ajax. In this case you should create a JS function that goes through all elements with the `innerText-src` attribute & runs an Ajax call to the given URL:

```
$('[innerText-src]').each(function() {

    var source = $(this).attr('innerText-src');

    if (source.length != 0) {

        /* get the url & content id */
        var url = source.split('?')[0],
            id  = source.split('?')[1].split('=')[1];

        /* setup data */
        var data = {id: id}

        /* ajax call */
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(content) {
                console.log(content);
                // Do something with the content
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });

    }
});
```